# Doesn't win-builder support parallelisation in vignettes or is this just bad practice?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cran

I'm creating a package with some embarrassingly parallel computations and am using the `doParallel` package to parallelise these. I moved to `doParallel` as `doMC` doesn't work on Windows. Since these are core functions in my package, the vignettes also establish a parallel backend.

`R CMD check` passes without any warnings on my Linux distro and on my colleague's Windows machine, however when submitting it to win-builder (see http://win-builder.r-project.org/), for carrying out an R CMD check on a Windows server I get the following error when it checks the vignettes:

```
* checking running R code from vignettes ... [15s] ERROR
Errors in running code in vignettes:
when running code in 'my_vignette.Rmd'

When sourcing 'my_vignette.R':
Error: 16 simultaneous processes spawned
Execution halted
```

As you can see, in the function I use half of the machine cores for the computation (as in the vignette this cannot be set to a user-specific variable). So my question is -- is this a problem with `win-builder` or is it just considered bad practice to have a parallel backend in a vignette? I should say that the package has functions which are quite computationally intensive so the vignettes will also be quite computationally demanding.

Thank you for any comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was told my the maintainer of the `win-builder` that for resource management, the number of processes on the parallel backend is limited to TWO. This is also a CRAN policy. Thanks to Uwe for the prompt reply.